# jquery validation events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugins

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

I am trying to find events like on error and on noerror so i can set a callback function when there is a error and there is no error

I am trying to do something like this

```
$("#form1").validate({
    onerror: function(form) {
        var frameWidth = jQuery(document).width();
        var frameHeight = jQuery(document).height() + 35;
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.myResize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
   },
   onnoerror: function(form) {
        var frameWidth = jQuery(document).width();
        var frameHeight =  380;
        parent.$.fn.colorbox.myResize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
   }
);
```

Because my pageopen in colorbox iframe and page get big when error shows up so I am resizing the page but I can't find any events like I added in code is there any way to do his

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what to do depends on how you're performing the validation (i.e., submit time or change-by-change), but there's a "submitHandler" callback that's called when the form is valid, and "showErrors" to display error messages when it's not valid.

Comment: this is exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: OK, well then there you have it.  The documentation for the plugin describes the parameter(s) passed in to those handlers.